# Best way to differentiate tabs with session id's in JS/HTML(and ruby)

Tags: javascript, html, sinatra

I have some code that does a jQuery post to my API, does some magic, and then uses Pusher to push data back to the browser.

Currently I am using Sinatra, pulling the session id, and putting it in a hidden value on the html. And then when my JS function is triggered by my button push, it pulls this value, and passes it to the API. Then my code just remembers and sets this as the channel ID and pushes data back.

It works quite well...except if I have more than one browser open, both have the same session id. So triggering my API on one pushes data to all open instances I have. My question is: is there a "best practice" way to do this and differentiate between tabs?

I could of course just generate a random number with JS and use that as my value, but for some reason it just seems wrong.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you want separate tabs to have separate sessions, then you just can't use a cookie for the session because cookies are the same for all tabs in a browser on the same site.  You can put the session in the URL as a query parameter and just make sure it is preserved as the user in that tab changes pages.  I know there are some Java-based back-end frameworks that do this.  You often see `sessionId=xxxxxx` in the URL.

Comment: I ended up doing something like what you said.  I just create a random 24 character "session id" that I pass in to my back end with my jquery post.  It is working great for me, but I thought there might be a better/more "standard" way of doing it.

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer to improve the site